# Is there a rule for realizing a-schwa before vowels as [r] at words boundaries?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

I know that Standard German pronunciation is strictly governed by rules, i.e. the pronunciation of originally German words are to a large extent predicted. However, I don't know whether there is a general rule for realizing a-schwa before vowels as [r] when it occurs at words boundaries.

Examples of [r]:

> hieraus, vorauf, voran, hierauf ***but not*** hier auf dem Tisch

Examples of [ɐ]:

> überall, überaus, allerorts, Vorabend, Lehrerassistent

I can make my own rules to fit the real pronunciatioin such as compound words vs. separate words or prepositions vs. content words and so on, but I can't see the difference between *voraus* and *überaus* for example? Is there a rule or should I always learn the pronunciation of each word separately?

Comment: Vowels as "r" ?

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann No, before vowels like those in the beginning of *aus, an, all, auf, assistent, abend, orts..*

Comment: I don't know if there is a known rule, but I think it might be that the first group are 2-syllable words and the second group words consist of more than two syllables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One possible rule:**

> **1.** If we have two combined prepositions, *r* sticks to the ***next*** preposition (vo|rauf, vo|ran).
>
> **2.** If we have a preposition combined with other word classes e.g., nouns, adverbs, verbs… etc., *r* sticks to the preposition and pronounced accordingly (für|einander, hie|raus).
>
> **3.** If we do not have a preposition, a-schwa is still pronounced a-schwa (aller|orts, Lehrer|assistent).
>
> **Two exceptions:** ***herein*** and ***vorüber*** pronounced with *r*.

In order to give a precise answer, I had to do a systematic search of all possible combinations of a compound adverb which is obviously the main culprit here. In the following I will provide some examples for each possible combination (some of them do not involve a-schwa but mentioned to clear the issue more):

**1.**  **Adverb + Adverb** (total 233 results): achteraus, herein, hierorts, hintenheraus, obenherein, obenherum.

**2.**  **Adverb + Preposition** (total 95 results): herab, heraus, heran, herauf, herüber, herum, herunter, hieran, hierauf, hierunter, hierin, hieraus.

**3.**  **Preposition + Adverb** (total 41 results): überaus, vorab, überübermorgen,  vorerst, vorüber.

**4.**  **Preposition + Preposition** (total 13 results): voran, voraus, vorauf.

**5.**  **Preposition + Pronoun** (total 33 results): füreinander, hintereinander, überall, übereinander, untereinander, voreinander, widereinander.

**6.**  **Noun + Adverb** (total 72 results): bergab, bergan, kopfvor, jahraus, jahrein, türaus, türein.

**7.**  **Adjective + Adverb** (total 78 results): geradeaus, hochauf, kurzum, querab, querüber, weitaus.

The big idea here lies in word formation. Some words can be a preposition and an adverb e.g., ab, aus, vor, über… etc. The same word is a preposition in some words but an adverb in others **sometimes in an unexpected way**.

> **Example 1:** ***aus*** is a preposition in *heraus, hieraus, voraus* but an adverb in *überaus, achteraus, jahraus, weitaus.*
>
> **Example 2:** ***ab*** is a preposition in *herab* but an adverb in *vorab*.
>
> **Example 3:** ***über*** is a preposition in *überaus, überall, herüber* but an adverb in *vorüber and querüber*.
>
> **Example 4:** ***Vor*** is a preposition in *voran, voraus, vorauf, vorerst, vorüber* but an adverb in *kopfvor*.

**Note 1:** I did not look for all possible combinations of words other than compound adverbs such as compound nouns or adjectives. but I will assume that this rule applies unless counterexamples are provided.

**Note 2:** In my search, I used [canoo](http://canoonet.eu/) to get these possible combinations and [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/) to check the pronunciation.

Comment: While I appreciate the work, do you plan to use these results in some other way than self-study?

Comment: @Janka Of course not. It's for private usage only, but I posted it here because it might help someone in the future who has the same question in mind.

Comment: I asked because we had to check if those observations are accurate, one by one.

Comment: I think you may be over-complicating this issue. As far as I can see, my suspicion that you may simply need to remember the set of prefixes that potentially "give away" their _r_ in prefix+preposition compounds remains unchallenged. Going through all of your examples, you apparently still could only come up with "[ʁ] words" that begin with _her-, hier-_ and _vor-_ and whose second element is (also) a preposition. The only false positive of this algorithm is _vorab_ (as far as I can see).

Comment: @johnl *vorab* is not false in neither of our algorithms because *ab* is an adverb and not a prepositioin. Your answer didn't address other cases or point whether it could be exceptions and didn't also mention why *vorab* is different from *herab*. The fact is some obvious things for native speakers are not obvious for non-native speakers. One thing I cared about in my whole question is to know whether I need to check my dictionary every time I encounter such words. Now I know the answer but after I checked out every possible word in German.

Comment: Well, sure, as I said, I don't know what the rule is, so we're both speculating here. I'm skeptical about your rule because it rests on premises that seem unnatural. In particular, the whole "acts as a preposition/adverb" distinction doesn't sound plausible to me. You're deep in morphological waters here - speakers don't know that. Take the word _vorauf_. Nobody uses that word. 95% of Germans will tell you they've never heard of it. Yet I bet most would still pronounce [ʁ]. But they have no clue what it means, and no clue if this is, etymologically, adverb _auf_ or preposition _auf_.

Comment: @johnl There is one little problem is that I'm not a native speaker and I don't have that instinct (yet).  Many expect too much of non-native speakers to know. It's obvious to them but not to us. About the word formation of *vorab* and the likes, it's from canoo. If you find a better sentence to describe this behavior of *ab*, feel free to edit my post. I edited it a little bit myself.

Comment: I understand that you are not a native speaker. My point is that if a word, which appears as part of a compound adverb, can be both a preposition and an adverb/particle/..., I find it implausible to have a phonological rule that hinges on the part of speech of the word in this particular compound because a speaker doesn't know that (and, in fact, can't know it in many cases since it's everything but obvious without additional etymological information). Speakers seem to have a pretty good idea of the set of prepositions, but they are not morphologists.

Comment: @johnI Your point is right, I totally agree. This can't serve as a rule for the vast majority of people, though it might give some explanation for words like *vorab*. Anyway, I hope who read this answer would be able to pronounce such words correctly since it serves at least as a nearly complete **list** of correct pronunciation.

Answer (score 4):

Phonetics/Phonology is not really my area of research, so someone else may be better equipped to respond, but it appears to me that this has to do with the boundaries of the (phonetic) syllables. If you look at *hieraus, voran, hierauf*, their common feature is that the *r* sticks to the preposition: hie|raus, vo|ran, hie|rauf. Unlike in your second group of examples, the word boundary is not the same as the syllabic boundary. Looking this up, this seems to be a pattern with specific prefixes. E.g., *Wiese*, The Phonology of German, 1996, 66, notes that

> Prefixes in general constitute their own, separate domain of
>   syllabification. There are two well-defined sets of exceptions. The
>   prefixes *her*+, *hin*+, and *vor*+ in combination with prepositions
>   (*her*+*an*, *hin*+*aus*, *vor*+*an*) are syllabified so that their
>   final consonant is onset to the second syllable [...] The other
>   exception is the suffix *in*-, which assimilates to following
>   consonants as in *illegal*, *irregulär*, *impotent*.

Comment: Is "dar-" as in "darauf", "darüber" also related to this?

Answer (score -1):

What a puzzling question! What is an "a-schwa"? Should we read "... a general rule for realizing a schwa before consonants as [r]". And even if, where would these schwa's be in the following examples?

*hieraus, vorauf, voran* don't have schwa's. *hier* in *hier auf dem Tisch* has one: /hi:ə/, but what does /hi:ə/ have in common with *vorauf*  /for'auf/ ?

*überall, überaus, allerorts, Vorabend, Lehrer, Assistent* do have a schwa: /y:bə/, /ɑlə/, /a:bnt/, sometimes /a:bənt/ etc.- but what do these examples and their schwa's have to do with the previous examples?

Is it possible that you have not yet understood that a schwa is this one: /**ə**/, and only this one?

Take a look at the *Vokaltrapez* on https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokaltrapez. The only phoneme that was given the name 'schwa' is the **ə** right in the middle.

You might want to reconsider your problem and your question(s). :-))

Cheers!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the question. It refers to https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_offener_Zentralvokal ("a-Schwa"), [ɐ], a vowel sound between [a] and [ə].

Comment: Maybe an example would clear it up: *vor* ends in a schwa but when *vor* is added to *auf* (vorauf), the schwa is pronounced *r* but when *vor* is added for example to *Abend*, the schwa is still pronounced a schwa and not *r*. The same applies for the rest of my examples.